# Chef: use kitchen input value in inspec command test

Tags: chef-infra, inspec

I'm attempting to use an input value from .kitchen.yml in an Inspec test like this:

**/.kitchen.yml**

```
- inputs:
  my_service: some_service_name
```

**/tests/my_test.rb**

```
describe command('/bin/some_app status (input('my_service'))')
  its('stdout') { should include 'foo' }
end
```

Unfortunately, I'm greeted with syntax errors when I try to `kitchen verify` the suite.
The goal is to test if the output of `/bin/some_app status my_service` contains `foo`.

Comment: what is the command you use to provide the  input? did you try to use the  `input()` in the  outer scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to the syntax issue. Correct syntax:

```
describe command("/bin/some_app status " + input("my_service"))
  its('stdout') { should include 'foo' }
end
```